# How does RAID perform in the context of virtualization/private cloud

Tags: virtualization, raid

Imagine a scenario: you've got one machine, several drives (SSDs, of course). You want to have several virtual machines in that machine. These machines might be:

- An active directory node
- A SQL Server node (only the server, not the actual data store)
- A web server node
- Just a node that has, say, XP x64 and is used for computation

So what I'm wondering is: since VMs are just files on disk, should I bother with RAID? For example, instead of having several disks I could stripe and mirror everything into one drive and then have that.

Or maybe I should just have one VM per drive and forget about RAID?

Comment: VM's, like any other files, work better with faster disk access. RAID can help that.  What's your actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @techie007 just want to set up IT infrastructure without buying lots of physical servers. thus, thinking of having many VMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID will give you physical level redundancy and your system will survive in case of drive's physical fault. So, I guess, if you need it - than go with RAID. If you can afford to lose data and/or spent time to recover your system - than do not do RAID setup.

RAID itself will not change anything for your VMs.